# Hook into the channel entry display

Tags: plugin

If I have channel tags in my template that look like this, is there an available hook to always run before the /exp:channel:entries?

I need to have something put at the bottom of every entry displayed without putting in a plugin tag into the template.

Is this at all possible?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="3" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|pagination"}

//do plugin stuff here without loading the tag.
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Check [Channel Module Extension Hooks](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel/index.html#channel-entries-tagdata)
You possible need

> **channel_entries_tagdata**($tagdata, $row, $this)
>
> Modify the tagdata for the channel entries before anything else is parsed.